# Send data from python program to arduino

Tags: python, arduino

I am trying to send data from python program. the data is in float and i need to send that data to arduino which will be processed to steering angles..
i tried with struct gave me type error
i also tried it parsing it.. but i dont know what to do next..
please help..

here's arduino code

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);

}
float f;

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(Serial.available()) {
    f=Serial.parseFloat();
    Serial.println(f);
  }

}
```

here's python code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import serial
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('Autopilot.h5')

def keras_predict(model, image):
    processed = keras_process_image(image)
    steering_angle = float(model.predict(processed, batch_size=1))
    steering_angle = steering_angle * 100
    return steering_angle


def keras_process_image(img):
    image_x = 40
    image_y = 40
    img = cv2.resize(img, (image_x, image_y))
    img = np.array(img, dtype=np.float32)
    img = np.reshape(img, (-1, image_x, image_y, 1))
    return img


steer = cv2.imread('steering_wheel_image.jpg', 0)
rows, cols = steer.shape
smoothed_angle = 0

ser = serial.Serial('com5', 9600)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('run.mp4')
while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.resize((cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV))[:, :, 1], (40, 40))
    steering_angle = keras_predict(model, gray)
    print(steering_angle)
    ser.write(str(steering_angle))
    cv2.imshow('frame', cv2.resize(frame, (500, 300), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA))
    smoothed_angle += 0.2 * pow(abs((steering_angle - smoothed_angle)), 2.0 / 3.0) * (
        steering_angle - smoothed_angle) / abs(
        steering_angle - smoothed_angle)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols / 2, rows / 2), -smoothed_angle, 1)
    dst = cv2.warpAffine(steer, M, (cols, rows))
    cv2.imshow("steering wheel", dst)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: some arduinos reset on new usb connection and spent some seconds in bootloader waiting for sketch upload

Comment: no that isn't what i asked.. i am trying to send data which is in float.. and arduino needs bytes to process.. my question is..
is my code right? data is reaching till arduino after being converted?
or there must be some changes done in the code?